# WPF Storyboard object reference

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a usercontrol which is a heart shape that I need to beat.  Here is my code:

```
<userControls:Heart x:Name="Heartbeat" Width="25" Height="25">
   <userControls:Heart.Resources>
       <Storyboard x:Key="HeartbeatStoryboard2X"
              RepeatBehavior="2x"
              Completed="Storyboard_Completed">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                             Storyboard.Target="{Binding ElementName=Heartbeat}"
                                             From="0.05" To="0.8" Duration="0:0:0.500">
            </DoubleAnimation>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                  Storyboard.Target="{Binding ElementName=Heartbeat}"
                  From="0.8" To="0.05" Duration="0:0:1.500">
                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                     <PowerEase EasingMode="EaseOut" Power="6" />
                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
            </DoubleAnimation>
        </Storyboard>
    </userControls:Heart.Resources>
    <userControls:Heart.Style>
         <Style TargetType="userControls:Heart">
             <Style.Triggers>
                   <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsHeartBeating}" Value="True">
                            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Name="HeartbeatStoryboard"/>
                             </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                   </DataTrigger>
          </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
  </userControls:Heart.Style>
```

The code in the codebehind is:

```
    public bool IsHeartBeating { get; set; }
    private bool m_restartedAnimation = false;
    private void Storyboard_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClockGroup clockGroup = sender as ClockGroup;
        Storyboard heartbeatStoryboard = clockGroup.Timeline as Storyboard;
        if (IsHeartBeating == true)
        {
            m_restartedAnimation = true;
            heartbeatStoryboard.Begin();
        }
        else
        {
            if (m_restartedAnimation == true)
            {
                heartbeatStoryboard.Stop();
            }
            m_restartedAnimation = false;
        }
    }
```

I keep getting two errors:

> MC3093    Cannot set Name attribute value 'HeartbeatStoryboard' on element 'BeginStoryboard'. 
>       'BeginStoryboard' is under the scope of element 'Heart', which already had a name registered when it 
>       was defined in another scope.

and

> XDG0062    Must have a Storyboard object reference before this trigger action can execute.

My heart does not have a Name set.
Any ideas?
TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say your heart doesn't have a name set, yet you refer to it twice in your storyboard with `ElementName=Heartbeat`? In any case, the problem is this line:

```
<BeginStoryboard Name="HeartbeatStoryboard"/>
```

That just gives the `BeginStoryboard` timeline element itself a name, I suspect what you actually intended was this:

```
<BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource HeartbeatStoryboard2X}"/>
```

UPDATE: looking closer there are actually a few problems, although I'd need to see an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to address them properly. First of all, you're already triggering the storyboard in your control's style, so you don't need to set `Storyboard.Target`. And even if you were, both that and `Storyboard.TargetProperty` should be set on the Storyboard, not the animation. Finally, when you call `heartbeatStoryboard.Begin` and `heartbeatStoryboard.Stop` you need to pass in the element (i.e. `this.Heartbeat`).

So your XAML needs to look something like this:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="HeartbeatStoryboard2X"
         RepeatBehavior="2x"
         Completed="Storyboard_Completed"
      Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
    <DoubleAnimation From="0.05" To="0.8" Duration="0:0:0.500" />
    <DoubleAnimation From="0.8" To="0.05" Duration="0:0:1.500">
        <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
            <PowerEase EasingMode="EaseOut" Power="6" />
        </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
    </DoubleAnimation>
</Storyboard>
```

And your storyboard handler needs ot look like this:

```
private void Storyboard_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClockGroup clockGroup = sender as ClockGroup;
    Storyboard heartbeatStoryboard = clockGroup.Timeline as Storyboard;
    if (viewModel.IsHeartBeating == true)
    {
        m_restartedAnimation = true;
        heartbeatStoryboard.Begin(this.Heartbeat);
    }
    else
    {
        if (m_restartedAnimation == true)
        {
            heartbeatStoryboard.Stop(this.Heartbeat);
        }
        m_restartedAnimation = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: As a follow on - I need to start the animation but the IsHeartBeat going to true is not caught (yes OnPropertyChanged is called and INotifyPropertyChanged implemented.  
The Binding to IsHeartBeating is not working